# How can I make Postfix reject mail transfers based on addresses?

Tags: postfix

I want to learn about running a mail server by running a mail server.

To be somewhat responsible and avoid being an open relay, I want Postfix to reject all mail that is not addressed to <valid user>@<hostname> OR (is from <valid user>@<hostname> AND the connection is coming from localhost). Will it do that by default or do I have to set some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of checks you can put in place inside `main.cf` which allow you to do exactly what you want. Some may be in place, others may not. For example Debian and Ubuntu often seem to have sensible defaults, whereas RHEL etc often do not.

In a canonical `main.cf` you would usually have `mydestination` to be a comma separated list of domain names allowed as destination domains. Furthermore you'd probably only allow accepting certain things such as relaying by setting `mynetworks` to a list of IP addresses and subnets (CIDR). And then, to put everything together based on (among other things) those two values you set `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, e.g. here an excerpt:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    ...
```

The order of the restrictions *does* matter. You can see how we already restrict taking in messages before we permit for `mynetworks`  (`permit_mynetworks`).

You best course of action is likely to read the excellent documentation, e.g. [here about the topic you seem most concerned about](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html).

Comment: You might want to elaborate on those non-sensible defaults that RHEL has. As it stands this is some good advice for how to avoid creating an open relay by accident, but it needs a little more effort to directly address the question.

Comment: You should also elaborate on those sensible defaults that Debian and Ubuntu supposedly have. Do you have any experience with _any_ of them?

Answer (score 3):

Postfix should be correctly configured to *not* open relay, out of the box. You would have to [explicitly change settings in order to make it an open relay](https://serverfault.com/a/470913/126632).